# populate a select based on the selection of a previous select with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, select

I have a select to select a country pull from all the countries in my database as per the code below:

```
<select name="country" id="country">
    <?php
    $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");

    $query = "SELECT country FROM countries";

    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

    printf ("<option value=Select>Select a Country</option>");
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     printf ("<option value=$myrow[country]>$myrow[country]</option>");

}

    ?>
</select>
```

Then I have another select where I want to pull all the cities from the country selected above. I tried the following code but it is not pulling anything:

I tried to get the country selected in 2 different ways as per the code:

1. $selectedCountry = $_GET['country'];
2. $selectedCountry = $_POST["country"];

and none of them seams to work, but If I change my $query to

$query = "SELECT city FROM cities where country = 'USA'";   then it works, so I'm guessing I'm not able to get the value of the country selected.

```
<select name="city" id="city">
    <?php
    $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");

    $selectedCountry = $_GET['country'];
    $selectedCountry = $_POST["country"];
    echo $selectedCountry;

    $query = "SELECT city FROM cities where country = ' $selectedCountry '";

    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }
    printf ("<option value=Select>Select a City</option>");
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     printf ("<option value=$myrow[city]>$myrow[city]</option>");

}

    ?>
</select>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Those two sections are part of the same form? $_GET and $_POST won't be set until you submit the form. Whatever script you call on submit will have access to the $_GET and $_POST arrays.

Comment: So, how can I get the value selected to passed and fill the second select based on the selection of the first select?

Comment: You will probably need to use ajax/javascript - http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2013/10/country-state-city-dropdown-using-ajax.html

Comment: I agree with Brett that Ajax is probably the way to go. Alternatively, you could store all the country/city combinations on the page somehow and have JavaScript access those, but that could get messy.